# Python installing pyttk package results error: subprocess-exited-with-error - ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, modulenotfounderror

I was trying to install pyttk package and i get the following error

```
Collecting pyttk
  Using cached pyttk-0.3.2.tar.gz (127 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [8 lines of output]
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
    File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\Aliha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9bqkh7pi\pyttk_814eb0b52ac14353b20fd79b4416949d\setup.py", line 2, in <module>
      import ttk
    File "C:\Users\Aliha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9bqkh7pi\pyttk_814eb0b52ac14353b20fd79b4416949d\ttk.py", line 36, in <module>
      import tkinter as Tkinter
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

Encountered error while generating package metadata.

See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Also when I use the command  "python -m tkinter" the GUI popsup

I was trying to install pyttk package to be able to use GUI tkinter package

Comment: If you can run "python -m tkinter" successful, then you have `tkinter` installed and it includes `ttk` sub-module.  So you don't need `pyttk` module which is very old and not updated for a long time.

Comment: @acw1668 The problem is when i try to run the program I get this error

"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\sme\timal_delete_user-master\timal_delete_user-master\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tkinter as tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'"

Comment: But you have said you can run "python -m tkinter", so `tkinter` module should be installed.

Comment: @acw1668 I can run it through CMD but in pycharm I get this error 
and adding the package there results the error mentioned above, any idea what is the solution?